# Which procedure is correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, error-analysis, computational-physics

A problem is given in my textbook pg.no-191 as

> Example 5.10 A solenoid has a core of a material with relative permeability $\mu_r=400$. The windings of the solenoid are insulated from the core and carry a current of $2A$. If the number of turns per unit length $N$ is $1000$ turns per metre, calculate (a) $|\mathbf{H}|$, (b) $|\mathbf{M}|$, (c) $|\mathbf{B}|$ and (d) the magnetising current $I_m$ .

But for (d) iam getting two different answers after following two different procedures. I know that The magnetising current Im  is the additional current that needs to be passed through the windings of the solenoid in the absence of the core which would give a $|\mathbf{B}|$ value as in the presence of the core.

*Case 1:* $B=\mu_0N(2+I_m)$

On solving (c) I will get $B=2\mu_r N=1.0 \textrm{T}$

On substitution I will get $I_m = 794 \textrm{A}$

*Case 2:* I know that $B=\mu_r \mu_0 NI=\mu_0N(2+I_m)$

Cancelling $\mu_0$ and $N$ on both sides

->  $2\mu_r=2+I_m$

Since $\mu_r=400$,

-> $800= 2+I_m$

--> $I_m = 798 \textrm{A}$

**SO WHICH PROCEDURE IS BETTER AND WHY OTHER IS WRONG ARE BOTH CORRECT?**

Link to my textbook:http://www.ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/leph105.pdf

Comment: I edited your question so it will be more likely to get a good answer. However, I may have contorted your original question by doing so. For example, for the first arrow in *Case 2*, I don't see why/how you neglected $I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both method are correct.
Difference is just there in appx. error.

Case 1) uses B = 1T

but actually, it has been approximated. Actual B = 1.00530965.

When you use this B , you get same answer as in case 2).

Case 2) Yeah ! Its much better to solve using this, since it removes π from both sides. This reduce error in computation of question.

Comment: For case 1 if I use 1.00530965 then also I would get 797 but 797 is not near to 794 . Also which of two would be the best?

Comment: More Correct answer is 798. So, method 2 is best, as I already mentioned in answer.

Comment: 797 is very near to 798. Still, you are getting error with method 1) because π has no definite value.